# On a button click I want to update query string and re-post the page with button click

Tags: asp.net, postback

I need to re-post a page on button click after updating the query string. On button_click event, I check if query string has a certain parameter and if it is not present then I want to append that parameter to query string and do a postback so that it comes back to button click event. Is it possible?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure why you would want to add the querystring and reprocess the button click, instead of doing it all in one cycle?

Answer (score 0):

You could put all your input buttons in a form tag which is using GET as its method.

This way every time you submit aka click one of your input buttons the query string will be updated.

Example:

```
<form method="GET">
    <input type="text" name="MyFirstInput" />
    <input type="text" name="MySecondInput" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

If you fill in "MyFirstInput" with say "abcdefg" and press the submit button then the query string will be updated with ...url...?MyFirstInput=abcdefg.  Then if you go back and you fill in both the MyFirstInput and the MySecondInput then the query string will be updated with both.

Keep in mind though you'll have to maintain the values on postbacks if you dont want users to continuously fill out the same fields over and over again.

Answer (score 0):

Causing a client to refresh just to add a query string parameter is very expensive(time consumed) operation. Avoid doing it.

Whatever logic requires you to have the query string parameter can be refactored to be based on a variable you set on the page.

To answer your question; yes, it is possible, but don't do it.

```
if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["myParam"]))
{
    Response.Redirect(Request.ApplicationPath + "?myParam=" + myValue);  
}
```